# Creating XNA 3.1 Project - Strange error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, xna

I've just downloaded xna 3.1 and installed it, when I'm trying to create a new XNA 3.1 project in VS 2008 C# EXPRESS I'm getting the following error: [image]

I've tried looking for a solution for this one, but haven't found any (the solutions are when opening an existing project while I'm trying to create a **new** project.

Thank you!

Comment: XNA 3.1 is an old version - why not use XNA 4.0 and VC# 2010 Express?

Comment: @Dr_Asik I need to use XNA 3.1 because I need it on .net 3.5